# Put infinitely many equilateral triangles of equal size on the plane

Tags: mathematics, geometry

...such that

1. There's no overlapping
2. No more such triangles can be added without overlapping.

Let $r$ be, on average, the ratio of the area covered by triangles with respect to the area which is not.

Q1: What is the minimum/infimum value of $r$?

Q2: If we use squares instead of equilateral triangles, how does $r$ change?

Comment: Does overlapping of edges or vertices count or only interiors?

Comment: @RossMillikan Only interiors.

Comment: Can't both equilateral triangles _and_ squares tile the plane?

Comment: @Someone The question is asking for the minimum area that can be covered such that no additional triangles can be placed without overlap.

Comment: _Oh,_ that makes more sense.

Comment: This is worthy of 2 questions. Likely different people find optimum for triangle vs square.

Comment: Can you clarify if R is area ratio of covered/uncovered or covered/total. Latter seems most intuitive, but your post suggests former.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Upper bound for the infimum:

> $$r = \frac {\sqrt{3}} {2(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3})} = \frac 3 2 - \sqrt \frac 3 2 \approx 0.28$$
>
>
>  **Correction:**
>
>  By OP's definition the value of interest is
>  $$R=\frac r {1-r} = \frac {2 \sqrt 6 -3} 5 \approx 0.38$$
>  Thanks to @Kris Van Bael for spotting the mistake.

Pattern:

> [image]

The red triangle is not part of the pattern but explains how rows are spaced.

Comment: By the OP’s definition of R, your solution is approx .38.

Answer (score 7):

Triangle upper bound  (worse than loopy walt's)

> $r = 8/19 \approx 42.10\%$

remark: As Kris noted in comments, I miscalculated, and some open areas can hold a triangle. I thought my solution was a local optimum, but it is not. Although that means the solution can 'easily' be fixed by rotating the green triangles, I am pretty sure the solution will get increasingly better until the triangles are rotated 30 degrees. And then (after resizing/repositioning), we end up in loopy walts solution. So my triangle solution does not add anything useful to the question after all.

> [image]
>  note: the black grid size is 27/4 triangles, which can be improved a tiny bit since the blueish triangles can be tilted a bit.

Square upper bound

> $r = \frac {\sqrt{2}} {(3-1/2\sqrt{2}) \times(1 + \sqrt{2})-\sqrt{2}} \approx 34.31\% $

pattern

> [image]

Comment: By the OP’s definition, your triangle value for R is actually approx 0.42.

Comment: Based on my calculation, I believe that your triangle solution isn’t valid. The drawing is not to proportion, there is actually room for a triangle left and right of the green triangles.

Comment: Kris 1 fixed;  2 Ill have a look when I have more time

Comment: I obtained the same result for your square solution.

Answer (score -2):

The minimum uncovered area is ZERO , when the Plane is tightly tiled with triangles ...

When we shrink the triangles a little , while keeping the centers unchanged , then no new triangles can be added yet uncovered area is not Zero and can increase ...

Eventually , when the shrinkage is enough , then we can add a new triangle which will partially share a base side 2 triangles while the other two sides will touch 2 triangles at the base vertexes near the top ...
This gives the maximum uncovered area ...

[[ I will add images & calculations a while later. ]]

Comment: Why is that particular configuration of triangles optimal for the task?

Comment: You're free to use these images. I had to mock it up to be sure what you meant. I'd be interested in the math behind this being optimal. [Starting with this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjpMb.png), you make them [smaller like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbxII.png) and keep [making them smaller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2M5ji.png) until more triangles fit in between. I think that last picture is past that point, actually, even though the triangles are a little larger than half the size of the starting point. I would not expect this to beat the current record of only 38% coverage.

Comment: Thank you for the Image Set , I will use it over the week end , @EngineerToast , I am currently stuck up with some thing else which makes me unable to make Images to update my Post. Due to that , I am unable to meaningfully reply to user Bass.